# jQuery .data() is not actual after adding new values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got div like

```
<div data-a="aa">   </div>
```

Then I'm getting its data with:

```
var data = $("div").data();
```

And its working fine. Then I'm adding new data like this via **data- attribute**:

```
$("div").attr("data-b", "bb");
```

Then I'm getting data again like

```
var updatedData = $("div").data();
```

However, the new value ( `data-b` attr with `bb` value ) is not there. Why is that? (I want to manage data via `data-` attributes)

**[Fiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/tTr97/2/)**

Using attributes is suitable in my case, so I **dont** want to use `.data("key", "val")`. `data-` attributes are valid anyway

Interesting thing is that when I add data- attribute before first call of .data() - it works ok. Is there a way to ignore or 'rebuild' cache of data then? [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tTr97/3/)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tTr97/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `data()` api, jquery uses an internal private data structure to store the data so the attribute value is not updated.

When you use the data api, there is no need to use the `data-` prefix.

So once you use the data api to read the values the attribute values are copied to the internal data structure thereafter any changes done to the attribute will not be reflected in the data api.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hH5uP/2/)

Comment: When I add attribute before first using of .data() - it works. Is there any way to ignore 'cache' of data? http://jsfiddle.net/tTr97/3/

Comment: Are the initial `data-*` attribute values copied upon the first `.data()` call, or when jQuery is loaded? Out of curiosity.

Comment: @George it is done as part of initial data lookup... so not when jQuery is loaded

Answer (score 4):

Use `.data("key","value")` to set the value

```
$("div").data("b", "bb");
```

Also use `.data("key")` to get the value

```
var data = $("div").data("b");
```

Comment: I use attributes data that is valid data solution. I know I can do it that way, but attributes are more suitable in my case. **This is not solution for my question** 'why data is not updated when I use **valid data attributes**'

Comment: @Kluska000 Read [Arun P Johny's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25116413/1612146), specifically, the last paragraph. Which answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add data to an element either you can use data() function by jQuery or you can manually add the 'data-attribute'

The issue you're facing is you can always GET as well as SET the data-attribute's value with data() function. But the attribute SET by this function won't be visible in HTML file.

In the below, 'data-c' won't be visible in the HTML file.

```
<div class='bar' data-a='avalue' data-b='bvalue'></div>

<script>
console.log($( "div" ).data());
$( "div" ).data('c','cvalue');
console.log($( "div" ).data());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dataset`

```
var article = document.querySelector('#div1'),
              updatedData = article.dataset;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTr97/4/)

Reference [JavaScript Access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)